# Calculating Velocity

Tags: android, physics

I am working on a very simple Physics game for Android where an object bounces up and down with some gravity (0 friction, ball should always reach same height). I want it to reach the same height on all devices (density independence). My game is coded with the following for the physics, which works perfectly fine on a 540 * 960 device.

Note: My game has a max FPS of 30

**physics code**

```
    //Instance variables
    private final float acceleration = .1f;
    private static float timePoint;
    private float velocityY = 0;

    //game loop code
    timePoint += 1;//updates every tick
    velocityY = velocityY - acceleration * timePoint;
    position.y = (int) (position.y - velocityY);
    if(position.y + bitMapHeight <= 0){
      velocityY = 30;
      timePoint = 0;
    }
```

When the ball hits the ground (y = 0) I simply apply a velocity of 30, which makes the ball reach a desired height on the 540 * 960 device. Of course multiple devices lead to major headaches, and this formula will not suite all of them. I think the best approach would be to somehow calculate the velocity based on screen height, but I'm not really sure what the best approach is for something like this. Below are some screenshots showing whats happening.

[image]

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful! Please let me know if any more details are required.

Comment: Why do you want to use pixels?

Comment: I don't want to use pixels, but I need some kind of measurement to base velocity off.

Comment: acceleration should be multiplied by elapsed time from last frame. You are multiplying it with total time so far (and calling it deltaTime). Good luck.

Comment: @Tanmay Patil multiplying by total time is exactly what I want, I just called it Delta since it sounded like a good name, edited my post so it's called timePoint*

Comment: You should calculate physics in real units (like meters), then convert to pixels when you draw it.

Comment: If you want to use total time, you should use `v = u + a * totalTime`. I was suggesting to use `v = v + a * deltaTime`. Right now you are using `v = v + a * totalTime` which is against definition of acceleration so I find it a bit unconventional that's all. (v = current velocity, u = initial velocity, a = acceleration).

Comment: @ Tanmay Patil I was just about to hop back on and reply to my first response but you beat me to it :) Was going to say for now I will leave the total time just to simplify the measurement problem I am facing but will definetly implement your suggestion in the future. Thanks

Comment: @bjb568 Lets assume that the ball bounces a total of 2 meters. How would you convert that to pixels and account for the pixel densities on different devices?

Comment: I dunno. Figure out the dimensions, figure out how large the viewable area should be, figure out the pixel:meter ratio. It depends on how you want to do it.

Comment: I know how to get the exact pixel density per inch of any device but I cannot find a way to get the total width and height of a device in inches. If anyone has a clue how to do that, I think I can create a formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize to those who posted on this for my delayed response. I found a solution that worked for me. Below is the approach I took.

1. Find the target height that the object should reach after it hits the ground (bottom of screen).

   ```
   //We want the object to bounce halfway on screen
   targetBounceHeight = metrics.heightPixels / 2;
   ```
2. Use physics calculation to find required velocity to reach point Y.

   ```
   double velocityI = Math.sqrt(2 * targetBounceHeight * acceleration);
   ```

I simply find the initial velocity required, then plug it into the original code snippet dynamically instead of the value 30 (see top post). This solution has worked on all tested devices perfectly. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve a similar problem in a 2D game I was working on a while ago.

I developed the initial physics and rendering functionality on my own Android device until it behaved nicely on that particular device. I then obtained 'baseline' values for the relevant variables (eg. pixels:meter as mentioned by bjb568), to achieve the correct velocities on my baseline device.

Then, to make the game behave in the same way on different devices/screens, I simply used the baseline values scaled by the ratio of the actual screen resolution and the baseline screen resolution.

My game used a SurfaceView, so the 'actual screen resolution' was basically determined by the width and height of the surface.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this on the onCreate:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    width = size.x;
    height = size.y;
```

With that you can get the values of the screen and, instead of using ´velocityY = 30;´ you can set it to ´velocityY= height/10´ for example

Answer (score 0):

Why you set velocityY = 30; after point reaches the bottom? I think that you should use perfectly elastic collision. So, you just need to set velocityY = -velocityY;

Comment: The initial starting point of the object will not be at the desired maximum height, so using perfectly elastic collision will not give the result I need.

Comment: Ok, but if you set one and the same y velocity for all phones, it will not give right lesult to.

Comment: Exactly, thats the problem this post is about :)